# Display posts in different columns

Tags: php, pdo, blogs, posts

Below is a code which gets blogs from database and displays it in single column on screen, I want to display blogs in multiple columns may be three,with each column displaying 10 blogs ordered by their id, so how to do that. If it is too long to answer here maybe mentioning any method that is easy to use can help me.

this is how I call posts from db:

```
$query = ("SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by,  category FROM blogs INNER JOIN 
categories ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id ORDER BY blogs_id desc LIMIT 10");
foreach($db->query($query)as $row){
$blogs_id = $row['blogs_id'];
$title = $row['title'];
$body = $row['body']; 
$posted_by = $row['posted_by'];   
}
echo "<h2>$title</h2>
      <p>$body</p>";
```

Comment: can u print_r your $result ?

Comment: this code works fine for single column

Comment: im not real sure of native php format though but I think your row only refers to the first item on your array.. that is why its echoing identical data..

Comment: make sure your result data is containing multiple indexes of the array.. iin my case I use foreach($result as $r){ $blogs_id = $r['blogs_id']; }

Comment: thanks do you know of any detailed tutorials on this, i am new to programming :)

Comment: uhmmm.. http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-MySQL-Display-Data-P281.html this could help.. as I said earlier im not really good with native language xD but all your questions are pretty research-able..also I luv tutsplus tutorials so I guess this channel is a good spot for learning.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gmW91JUuxw&list=PLmdL_IinP2O4tLZTj38MCP19usFHBXGKL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code below it is quite easy to change the number of columns any time you want.

```
<tr>
<?php do { //horizontal looper?>
          <td><div><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>
          <div><?php echo $row['body']; ?></div>
          <div style="height:20px;"></div></td>
          <?php
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!isset($nested_List)) {
  $nested_List= 1;
 }
 if (isset($row) && is_array($row) && $nested_List++%3==0) {
   echo "</tr><tr>";
 }
} while ($row); //end horizontal looper 
?>
```

This will give you three columns.

Notice that your table row starts outside of the loop. Then this line `echo "</tr><tr>";` ends your table row and starts a new one each time the number of desired columns has been reached. In the above code it's 3.

To change the number of columns simply change `$nested_List++%3==0` to `$nested_List++%5==0` and you will have 5 columns.

**EDIT**

<strike>Place something similar to this at the **top** of your page above `<doctype><html><head>`</strike>

All together it should look similar to this...

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; $db = 'database_name'; $user = 'database_user'; $pw = 'database_password';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8', $user, $pw);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by,  category FROM blogs INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id ORDER BY blogs_id desc LIMIT 10";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$totalRows = $query->rowCount();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<?php do { //horizontal looper?>
          <td><div><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>
          <div><?php echo $row['body']; ?></div>
          <div style="height:20px;"></div></td>
          <?php
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!isset($nested_List)) {
  $nested_List= 1;
 }
 if (isset($row) && is_array($row) && $nested_List++%3==0) {
   echo "</tr><tr>";
 }
} while ($row); //end horizontal looper 
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course you can "include" or "require" your connection file in your usual manner and change `$conn` to match your code if necessary.

Comment: If your going to downvote please be man/woman enough to justify it. What is wrong with the code? Maybe I can learn something. After all, that's why we are all here. Right? This code works and does exactly what the OP wants. Have you even tried it before being so fast with your clicking finger?

Comment: thanx for help it shows error  "Call to a member function fetch() on string in" for this line `$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` may be because I am using simple query here and not prepared statement for calling blogs from database.

Comment: Yes... you should protect yourself from sql injection attacks by using `pdo_mysql` and prepared statements. I can provide an example if needed. just let me know.

Comment: okay now that error is solved using pdo prepared, but undefined variable row for line 3 and 4 as we are calling  `$row['title']` and `$row['body']` beforw defining variable row.

Comment: Yes, your sql query should come first. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: if you don't mind will you please help me once again, I was previously using this code which made the title of post it's link to view full post as I showed only 250 chars of body on main page, it worked fine, code was   `<?php // some code to call title and other stuff from db  echo "<h2><a href='viewpost.php?blogId=" . $row['blogs_id'] . "'>$title</a></h2>"; ?>`    but now given your code how to add code of mine to yours `<?php echo $row['title']; ?>` so that once again title of post opens the full post.

Comment: Changing `<div><?php echo $row['title']; ?></div>` to `<div><h2><a href="viewpost.php?blogId=<?php echo $row['blogs_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></h2></div>` should do it.